Excel input field for a drawing (signature)
I have an excel file (with macros) in which customers can make their choices in a dropdown menu.
These choices are entered on a tablet in the excel file.
Now I am looking for an input field where the customer can put a drawing (or signature) in an input field with their finger (or pen) on the tablet.
This can be a control element with VB or a macro.
Does anyone have an idea?
Ps, I use Office 365.

To add a signature input field in Excel using VBA, enable the Developer tab and insert a UserForm. Add an InkPicture control to the UserForm for drawing. If the control is not available, you can add it using the "Additional Controls" dialogue box:

